# Deploying my asp.net MVC on production on different port number , comparing to staging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have my asp.net mvc web application deployed inside our staging server on the following URL :-
Stagingserver:80/projectA
Now I have created a web deployment package and I copy the web deployment file into the production server. Now I need to deploy our application to different port on production such as :-
Productioserver:5444/ProjectA
So generally speaking should I use the same staging port number on production ? or there is no restrictions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mvc application does not care which port/server you it run on. You don't have to use the same port number. There are no restrictions.